# Is there a Hyperlink widget in Perl Tk?

Tags: perl

I have google-d all around to search if Perl Tk has a hyperlink widget.
This is a straightforward Entry Textbox (or label) that display a hyperlink, with mouse changes to "hand" during hover and button 1 click invokes a command.

Is there an existing one?

Comment: Maybe you could simulate the widget using tags: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=667664

Comment: h%c3%a6gland@ this is what i eventually did, but as this seems like a day-to-day need in our days... i thought maybe there is something more solid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now. Feedback welcome: https://metacpan.org/pod/Tk::HyperlinkButton

Sample:

```
$parent->HyperlinkButton(-text => 'https://metacpan.org');
```